# Does the merge-squash strategy work correctly?

Tags: git, bitbucket

Merge branches into main with squash merge strategy

I see such a picture, I want to make sure if branches are actually being merged correctly?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zwCl5.png

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing to find out. The history you see is all that the history knows.

The whole point of "squash merge" is that it is *not a merge*. All you are doing is creating a commit that expresses the whole of the feature branch, and adding it on to the end of main branch. There is *no connection* between that commit and the feature branch; you have effectively erased from the history any knowledge of how that commit got there.

That is one reason why I do not like squash merge. (Another reason is that, because this is not a merge, the point of divergence of the feature branch is not changed, and so if you accidentally keep using the feature branch and try to squash merge again later, you are very very likely to get conflicts.)

If you want traditional "train tracks" that diverge from the main branch and come back to the main branch, showing you the actual history, use a *real* merge.